# Cannot input text (email) with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use a bot with Selenium to input email and a password. Using Best Buy's website.

This is currently the block of code I have:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/input[@id='fld-e']").send_keys("EMAIL@gmail.com")
```

Yet no input is being sent when I actually run the program. Here is the HTML code attached to the email block, along with the XPath that I pulled from a chrome extension:
I've tried using .find_element_by_class_name("fld-e")

```
<input class="tb-input " type="email" autocomplete="off" id="fld-e" name="fld-e" placeholder="" required="" value="">

/html/body/div[@class='cia-app-container']/div[@class='cia-actual-full-page-wrapper lv']/section[@class='cia size-l cia--two-column-v2']/main[@class='cia-wrapper container']/div[@class='cia-wrapper__main']/div[@class='cia-content js-cia-content']/div[@class='cia-main-container']/div[@class='cia-settings-container']/div/div[@class='cia-signin']/form[@class='cia-form ']/div[@class='cdi-input cdi-wrapped-text']/div[@class='tb-input-wrapper   tb-input-wrapper-full-width']/input[@id='fld-e']
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: "/" is for absolute path... so it's probably looking for the first div.  Use "//" for any or all "input"s. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']")
```

If it won't work, add to your question more html code which you are working with.
You can also try `driver.find_element_by_id("fld-e")` but I have some doubts that it will work.

Also, wait until the field is clickable.